# views exposed filter to have dropdown of entity reference in cutstom entity

Tags: views, 8, entities, console

I generated with drupal console utility my own module and content entity code. After I added a user entity reference field and a taxonomy term entity reference field.

Now I'm listing my content with views, I don't do nothing with the code generated the integration is done.

But, when I expose a filter by taxonomy field and user field it doesn't give me the option to show as a dropdown, it directly appears as a textfield.

In others views, listing nodes with entity reference fields, if I add exposed filter of entity reference  offers to me a dropdown or autocomplete widget.

What I have to change to my entity to have dropdown select for my entity reference field as exposed filter in a view?

Here is the field definition in the Entity class

```
    $fields['term_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Log type'))
  ->setDescription(t('The term ID of the Log entry type.'))
  ->setRevisionable(FALSE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default:taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', 
    array(
      'target_bundles' => array(
        'logs_type' => 'logs_type'
    )))
  ->setTranslatable(FALSE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'inline',
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term',
    'weight' => -2,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'weight' => -2,
    'settings' => array(
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => '60',
      'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
      'placeholder' => '',
    ),
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Update:

I achieve to have a dropdown in the exposed filter in my view creating the file mymodule.views.inc and puting this code:

```
function log_activity_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['log']['term_log_tid_depth'] = array(
    'help' => t('Display content if it has the selected taxonomy terms, or children of the selected terms. Due to additional complexity, this has fewer options than the versions without depth.'),
    'real field' => 'term_id',
    'argument' => array(
      'title' => t('Log type (with depth)'),
      'id' => 'taxonomy_index_tid_depth',
      'accept depth modifier' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'title' => t('Has taxonomy terms (with depth)'),
      'id' => 'taxonomy_index_tid_depth',
    ),
  );
}
```

But when I choose a term to filter the view, it does not return any item and it should do so.

Answer (score 4):

As Berdir said, as long as https://www.drupal.org/node/2429699 is not ready, you need to provide your own Views Filter plugin.

I created this plugin, based on TaxonomyIndexTid, for Nodes, see https://gist.github.com/StryKaizer/ae1cb9abc4844a9e7ac12317a9d84a78

You need to place this file in a custom module at yourmodule/src/Plugin/views/filter/NodeIndexNid.php, and also implement hook_views_data_alter in your yourmodule.module file, like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_views_data_alter().
 *
 * Views integration for entity reference fields which reference nodes.
 * Adds a term relationship to the default field data.
 *
 * @see views_field_default_views_data()
 */
function yourmodule_field_views_data_alter(array &$data, FieldStorageConfigInterface $field_storage) {
  if ($field_storage->getType() == 'entity_reference' && $field_storage->getSetting('target_type') == 'node') {
    foreach ($data as $table_name => $table_data) {
      foreach ($table_data as $field_name => $field_data) {
        if (isset($field_data['filter']) && $field_name != 'delta') {
          $data[$table_name][$field_name]['filter']['id'] = 'node_index_nid';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Views currently only offers that for taxonomy_term references, as taxonomy.module provides a special Views integration.

There are core issues open to make this generic, for example: https://www.drupal.org/node/2429699.

Until that is resolved, you have to provide your own Views Filter plugin for this, based on \Drupal\taxonomy\Plugin\views\filter\TaxonomyIndexTid, and add a views_data handler to your entity type where you override the used filter for that field, like taxonomy.module does for all entity reference fields pointing to terms in taxonomy_field_views_data_alter()

Comment: I added hook_field_views_data_alter() to my custom entity module and I added \Drupal\my_custom_entity\Plugin\views\filter\TaxonomyIndexTid. But I doesn't work, I don't know what I have to change to make it work.

Comment: That hook is for field-type providing modules, for a custom entity type it belongs in your EntityViewsData handler. Also, you'll have to share your code or we won't be able to help more.

Comment: I solved adding a relation with taxonomy, and then in the filter section appear the filter of Term as dropdown or autocomplete. I think this question can help me with a filter for a date field, but my solution doesn't work for a date field :(

Answer (score 1):

The module [Entity Reference Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_exposed_filters) offers the possibility to generate a Views exposed filter of the referenced Titles entities.